# Encode JWT with google-auth-library-ruby 0.9+

Tags: ruby, google-compute-engine

I am currently trying to set up sending Objects to Google for [S2AP](https://developers.google.com/save-to-android-pay/).
Google recommends to sign JWTs like [this](https://developers.google.com/save-to-android-pay/reference/s2w-reference#s2w-jwt):

```
jwt = {
   "iss"=> SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
   "aud" => "google",
   "typ" => "savetoandroidpay",
   "iat"=> Time.now.utc.to_i,
   "payload" => {
     "loyaltyObjects" => [], #Loyalty objects
     "offerObjects" => [], #Offer objects
     "loyaltyClasses" => [], #Loyalty classes
     "offerClasses" => [] #Offer classes
   },
   "origins"=> ['http://baconrista.com', 'https://baconrista.com']
}
private_key = Google::APIClient::PKCS12.load_key(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY, 'notasecret')
jwtEncoded = JWT.encode(jwt, private_key, "RS256")
```

However, since [0.8](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/MIGRATING.md#migrating-from-version-09x-to-010) is no longer the standard, and `Google::APIClient` is no longer supported, I cannot find out how to Sign that JWT with the provided JSON file from a Compute engine service account.

I currently have everything else set up, to generate access tokens to speak with googles API with OAuth2 authentication, but cannot for the life of me figure out how to encode these JWTs.

For reference, this is how you get the access token from Google with the ruby [gem](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client)

```
compute = Google::Apis::ComputeV1::ComputeService.new
File.open(CONFIG[:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS], "r") do |json_io|
  compute.authorization = Google::Auth::DefaultCredentials.make_creds(scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/wallet_object.issuer', json_key_io: json_io)
end
TOKEN = compute.authorization.fetch_access_token!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get around the lack of ability of signing a jwt using the newer service (which isn't fully finished) I ended up pulling the private_key out of the json keyfile they have, then sign it like so:

```
def create_signed_JWT(obj, type)
  JSON.parse(File.open(keyfile.path, 'rb').read)
  jwt = {
    iss: credentials['client_email'],
    aud: "google",
    typ: "savetoandroidpay",
    iat: Time.now.utc.to_i,
    payload: {
      "#{type}Objects": obj
    },
    origins: [ "https://#{CONFIG[:domain]}", "http://#{CONFIG[:domain]}" ]
  }
  JWT.encode(jwt, OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(credentials['private_key'], nil), "RS256")
end
```

obj is the offer/loyalty object in json format, 
type is the type of object